# Resumable upload - Google Drive API : Unable to fetch the resumable session URI from POST request

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api

For my Flutter application, I have implemented Resumable upload from google drive API to upload large files to google drive.

In resumable upload approach POST and PUT request are done.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-uploads

when POST request is successful the response includes Location header that specifies the resumable session URI.

Implemented code logic as per the drive API article to fetch resumable session URI

```
      Uri uri = Uri.parse('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable');
      var authToken = headers['Authorization'];
      String body = json.encode({
        'name' : fileName,
        'originalFilename' : URN,
        'parents' : [monthFolderId],
        'contentHints' : [{
          'thumbnail' : {
            'mimeType' : 'image/png',
            'image' : base64Image
          }
        }]
      });

      final initialStreamedRequest = new http.StreamedRequest('POST', uri)
        ..headers.addAll({
          'Authorization': authToken!,
          'X-Upload-Content-Length' : zipFileLength.toString(),
          'X-Upload-Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream',
          'Content-Length' : utf8.encode(body).length.toString(),
          'Content-Type' : 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        });

      initialStreamedRequest.sink.add(utf8.encode(body));
      initialStreamedRequest.sink.close();

      http.StreamedResponse response = await initialStreamedRequest.send()
          .onError((error, stackTrace) {
              return Future.error(error!);
      });

      String? sessionUri;
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        sessionUri = response.headers['location'];
      }
```

Above code is working fine for smaller files less than 2MB and resumable session URI is available in header

[image]

But unable to fetch the resumable session URI for files more than 2MB. The POST request is throwing 400 Bad request error. Tested with multiple files still throwing error for files in POST request

[image]